# In routing I cant get index as controller or method

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I am studying MVC PHP - but I have a problem in routing. I have used `.htaccess` for `get` method, controller and parameters by entering method and controller in URL after site root.

For example :

`127.0.0.1/mvc/user/edit`

`(mvc = site root in local status)`

User works as controller and edit works as method.

but if entering `127.0.0.1/mvc/index/index` my output is null.

my code is in `.htaccess:`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: "Magic" seems to be when processing `url` parameter within your code. I can't see anything wrong with situation described in your question. You should debug your url parsing logic in app.